# How can I call an editor command from a vimscript?

Tags: vim

I want to remove an unwanted scrollbar from taglist. I created a function and a command like this:

```
function s:TlistWaToggle()
    normal :TlistToggle<cr> " <- this does not work
    set guioptions-=r
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 -bar TlistWaToggle call s:TlistWaToggle()
```

I want to wrap the call to :TlistToggle together with the command to remove the right scrollbar (I have that setting of course, but it always reappears, so this is a workaround). Currently my :TlistWaToggle doesn't do anything. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim script uses ex commands, and apparently `:TlistToggle` is an ex command…

```
function! s:TlistWaToggle()
    TlistToggle
    set guioptions-=r
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @sidyll's answer: `:normal` is not a `:*map`, it accepts only raw character strings. Correct command will be `execute "normal! :TlistToggle\<CR>"` (or `execute "normal! :TlistToggle\n"`). Note that you should not use non-banged version in your scripts.

I don't think you will ever use `:normal!` to execute an ex command, but my answer would be useful when you want to pass any other special character. It also applies to `feedkeys()` call.

By the way, comments and other commands will be considered part of string passed to `:normal` command.